# Does there exist two h-equal but not h-equivalent topological spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory, retraction

In his "Theory of retracts", Borsuk defines the concept of h-dominance (h is for homotopically), that is: given two (in this post i consider only Hausdorff spaces) topological spaces $X,Y$ we say that $X$ h-dominates $Y$ if there is an h-map of $X$ into $Y$ and in this case we write $Y\underset{r}{\leq} X$.

We say that a map $f\colon X\mapsto Y$ is a h-map provided that there exists a map $g\colon Y\mapsto X$ such that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to the identity  of $Y$. If $X\underset{r}{\leq} Y$ and $Y\underset{r}{\leq} X$ we say that these two spaces are h-equal.

My question is: does there exist two h-equal but not [h-equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence) topological spaces? More explicitly i want an example (if there is one) of two spaces $X,Y$ not h-equivalent and maps $f_1,f_2\colon X\mapsto Y$ and $g_1,g_2\colon Y\mapsto X$ such that $f_1\circ g_1$ is homotopic to the identity  of $Y$, while $g_2\circ f_2$ is homotopic to the identity  of $X$ (if i didn't understand bad).

Comment: While I do suspect there are examples, even in CW complexes, they necessarily have the same homotopy groups for $n\geq 2$ because for abelian groups being mutual direct summands implies they are isomorphic.

Comment: I’ll also note that given two groups such that each is the nonnormal part of a semidirect product of the other, the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces for each will be an answer to this question.

Comment: Can you espand your comment? I don't know what are the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces. And why don't you put as an answer?

Comment: Eilenberg-MacLane spaces are spaces parametrized by a group and a number. They can be used to transfer information between groups and topological spaces. The reason I didn’t post an answer is because this is only showing it is implied by a group theory problem.